# how to add count with username?

Tags: php, mysqli

hello everyone I am making a faucet list like Service

now I am just  wondering how would I display
their username with created and last updated list with their total faucets based on their username

I got a photo what I like it to look like and
I just don't have any
clue how to make it work :/

what I like it to look like
[image: database table for list]

database table for users

[image: what I like it to look like]

database table for the list

[image: database table for users]

the code

```
<?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM list  ";
     $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
     if( $result )    
     while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?> 
           <table class="table table-striped" id="faucetlist" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th><center>Faucetlist</center></th>    
                <th><center>Created</center></th>                          
                <th><center>Last updated</center></th>
                <th><center>faucets</center></th> 
                 </tr>
                </thead>                      
             <tr>             
            <td><center><?php echo $user["username"]; ?></center></td>   
             <td><center><?php echo date('l jS F Y' , strtotime($user['Published']));?></center></td>              
            <td><center><?php echo date('h:i A' , strtotime($user['last_update']));?> </center></td>   
             <td><center>FAUCETS COUNT GO HERE </center></td>   

              </table>                    
       <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You need to join the two tables in your query.

Comment: I think you have the wrong labels on your pictures.

Comment: Use `COUNT(list.id)` and `GROUP BY `users.id` in your query to get the counts.

Comment: what wrong labels?

Comment: The one where you say "database table for list" contains what you want it to look like.

Comment: like this?
SELECT * FROM list LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = list.id WHERE list.approved='1' COUNT(list.id) AND GROUP BY users.id

Comment: Of course not, that's not even valid syntax. `COUNT(list.id)` has to go in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: OK will i give up finding out how to join tables thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change your query and follow this code**

```
<?php
         $sql = "SELECT list.*,count(username) as faucet  FROM list  GROUP BY username";
         $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
         if( $result )    
         while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?> 
               <table class="table table-striped" id="faucetlist" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th><center>Faucetlist</center></th>    
                    <th><center>Created</center></th>                          
                    <th><center>Last updated</center></th>
                    <th><center>faucets</center></th> 
                     </tr>
                    </thead>                      
                 <tr>             
                <td><center><?php echo $user["username"]; ?></center></td>   
                 <td><center><?php echo date('l jS F Y' , strtotime($user['Published']));?></center></td>              
                <td><center><?php echo date('h:i A' , strtotime($user['last_update']));?> </center></td>   
                 <td><center>FAUCETS COUNT GO HERE </center><?php echo $user['faucet'];   ?></td>   

                  </table>                    
           <?php } ?>
```